# Schnorr Digital Signature

Tags: elliptic-curves, signature, schnorr-signature

I tried to rewrite the Schnorr signature algorithm for elliptic curves but I wanted to be sure to have not done any errors. So I would be very happy if someone could look over this algorithm and tell me if I have done anything wrong, or not precise enough:

---

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$ (first question, is it here as in the ECDSA, that either $q=p$ an odd prime or $q=2^m$?) with parameters such that $E$ is a cryptographically safe curve.

**Key Generation:**

Choose $P\in E(\mathbb{F}_q)$ of prime order $l$, where $l$ is a large prime.

Choose $1 < a < l$ random and calculate $Q = a*P$. Then the public information is $E, \mathbb{F}_q, Q, P$ and the private signature key is $a$.

**Signature Scheme:**

- Choose a random $1 \leq k < l$
- Compute $S_0 = kP = (x_0,y_0)$
- Compute $s_1 = H(m||x_0)$, where $H$ is a hash function, $x_0$ is the integer value of $x_0$ and $m$ is the message.
- Compute $s_2 \equiv k + a*s_1 \text{ (mod }l)$

The digital signature is $(S_0,s_2)$ and Alice sends $(m, (S_0,s_2))$ to Bob.

**Verification**

Bob verifies if $s_2*P=S_0+H(m||x_0)*Q$.

This works since: $$s_2*P=S_0+H(m||x_0)*Q$$ $$\Leftrightarrow s_2*P-H(m||x_0)*Q = S_0$$ $$\Leftrightarrow (k+a*s_1)-H(m||x_0)*a*P = S_0$$ $$\Leftrightarrow kP + a*H(m||x_0)*P-a*H(m||x_0)P=S_0=k*P$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, pretty much the same groups usable for ECDSA are usable for Schnorr signature. That was in [Sc91] (see bibliography in [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/48528/555)):

> It is possible to implement the above signature and authentication scheme using a finite group $G$ other than the subgroup $\mathbb Z_p^*$ of units in  $\mathbb Z_p$ (..) Examples of suitable groups are e.g. class groups and elliptic curves $E(K)$ over a finite field $K$.

It looks like you invented yet another variant of the Schnorr signature algorithm for elliptic curves, not among the about 6 in [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/50202/555). Yours sends a group element rather than a hash as the first part of the signature (thus more directly matching the transformation to signature of the Schnorr indetification protocol, and allowing a more direct proof of security). This has a strong taste of EC-FSDSA (Elliptic Curve Full Schnorr Digital Signature Algorithm) of ISO/IEC 14888-3 ([OID 1.0.14888.3.0.12](http://oid-info.com/get/1.0.14888.3.0.12)), but:

- For some reason you compute $H(m\|x_0)$ rather than $H(x_0\|y_0\|m)$ in said standard; hereafter I write $H(\dots)$. For an ideal hash and proofs in the ROM, hashing $m$ first or second is immaterial, and I can't decide if it makes any security difference for practical hashes. Not hashing $y_0$ might cost some security.
- Your verification procedure omits to verify that $S_0$ is a point on the curve, which seems risky since you perform point addition on that. The standard mandates this check.
- My understanding is that the standard does $Q=-a\times P$ (as suggested by Schnorr as soon a [Sc89]), so that verification can compute $s_2\times P+H(\dots)\times Q$ and compare it to $S_0$, with two advantages:

  - the computation of $s_2\times P+H(\dots)\times Q$ can use the simplest forms of [Shamir's trick, or others](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/8586/555)
  - checking that $S_0$ is a point on the curve becomes redundant.

Note: for elliptic curves $y^2\equiv x^3–3x+b\pmod p$ at least (including NIST's FIPS 186-4 curves over prime fields), while you are at not hashing $y_0$ and using something non-standard, you could as well omit $y_0$ from the signature, with verification computing $s_2\times P+H(\dots)\times Q$ and comparing it's $x$ coordinate to $x_0$. That shortens the signature from $6b$ to $4b$ for $b$-bit security, and (for ideal hash) costs at most 1 bit of security (perhaps nothing), since $y$ can be found from $x$ within sign.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I have only one question left. Why should the EC-SDSA rather be implemented with $H(x_0||y_0||m)$ than $H(x_0||m)$? What is the profit of inlcuding the $y$-coordinate? (I do not have access to the ISO/IEC 14888-3 paper explaining the standards.)

Comment: @Luca: EC-SDSA (resp. EC-SDSA-opt and EC-FSDSA) use $H(x_0\|y_0\|m)$ (resp. $H(x_0\|m)$ and $x_0\|y_0$ ) as the first component of the signature. Sending the un-hashed $k×P$ (as EC-FSDSA and you do) allows a simpler proof, but eats more space if $y_0$ is included. I do not know a good reason to use $y_0$ in either EC-SDSA or EC-FSDSA, at least for NIST's FIPS 186-4 curves over prime fields, where for ideal hashes $y_0$ can demonstrably be replaced by a single bit, hence gives at most 1 bit of security. My understanding is that [NSW09] concurs that we can safely remove $y_0$ as in EC-SDSA-opt.